# How can i fetching,viewing and updating checkbox values stored in db

Tags: php, mysql, database, checkbox

i have a html form that has a more then 30 checkboxes. checkboxes are used to select for different service.

I want to store those all value in 1 Database field seperated by , those could be numeric or string. Code for inserting checkbox values is as follows:

```
 <form method="post" action="posted.php">
    Option 1: <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="1" /><br />
    Option 2: <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="2" /><br />
    Option 3: <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="3" /><br />
    Option 4: <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="4" /><br />
    Option 5: <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="5" /><br />
    Option 6: <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="6" /><br />
    Option 7: <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="7" /><br />
    Option 8: <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="8" /><br />
    Option 9: <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="9"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

After successful submission off course i need to fetch those data in the corespondent check box while update.

Please response me as soon as possible with complete PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON. From this:

```
Option 1: <input type="checkbox" name="myval[option_name1]" /><br />
Option N: <input type="checkbox" name="myval[option_nameN]" /><br />
```

Store:

```
$model->field = json_encode($_POST['myval']);
```

Or comma-seporated (if you really want):

```
$model->field = implode(",", $_POST['myval']);
```